# Control UIView Location in ScrollView?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have a ScrollView that contains 3 TableView's inside a StackView.  The user can swip/segment control horizontally between each TableView, and they effectively see the appropriate TableView fill up 2/3rds of the screen when scrolled to.  In the vertical empty space I'm trying to have a standalone View "slide" in/out of the viewer's screen the same as the TableViews, however only above 2 of them.  Here's my layout:

[image]

I can't figure out a way for this View to remain stationary above TableView 2 + 3, yet slide out for TableView 1.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, do the red views scroll with the scroll view or not?

Comment: Ideally, yes.  So if the user is on TableView 1 the UIView is not visible, however if they scroll to TableView 2 the UIView slides in as well, and stays static if the user scrolls to TableView 3.

Comment: First thing I'd do is get rid of the stack view (no reason for it; there are only 3 subviews and nothing about their placement will ever change). I'd add the table views directly to the scroll view and then--if I understand you correctly--I'd add the red views to the scroll view as well, pinned to the top of their respective table views. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: My apologies for not explaining the issue very well; the red UIView is a single view.  I’d like it to stay static whether the user scrolls to either TableView 2 or 3.  If they scroll to TableView 1 it scrolls out of view.

Comment: I was confused because in the diagram there are 2 red views. And finally, when the first table comes into view, the red view doesn't scroll out of view, it animates out of view, correct (slide out, fade out, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, slides out of view.  Ideally in the same motion that TableView 2 is making to slide out so they look cohesive. Thanks!

Comment: You have 2 options here. (1) You can add the red view to the view (and not the scroll view) and change the constant of its (leading or centerX) constraint in the scroll view's `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method. (2) You can add the red view to the scroll view and pin it above the second table view and then in the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method, whenever the offset is greater than or equal to `x` (`x` being the offset when you want it to stop moving), offset the constraint constant with the offset of the scroll view so that it doesn't move when you slide between tables 2 and 3.

Comment: That makes sense; I’ll check it out.  Thanks for the direction!

Comment: What I would do if I were you is put `print(scrollView.contentOffset.x)` inside the scroll view's `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method and play with it until you get a good handle on it. Then add the red view to the scroll view and update its leading or centerX constant in the delegate method.

Comment: I'm using scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).x inside of func scrollViewWillBeginDragging to programmatically change a segment controller I've got at the top of the screen based on user scrolling, sounds like similar logic.

Comment: Using `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` will only work on physical finger drags. `scrollViewDidScroll` will work no matter what moves the scroll view (a button, the user, etc.).

Comment: Understood; thanks again!